# fgetc - Segmentation fault

Tags: c

Estoy creando un simulador de una shell pero la orden `c = fgetc (stdin)` me produce una violación de segmento si no introduzco ningún caracter. ¿De que manera podría solucionarlo?

He declarado la variable `c` de tipo `int`.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Podrias poner un poco de código, tal vez el problema este en otro lado

Comment: No, el error lo produce solo ahí. Lo he comprobado con gdb

Comment: ¿c es una variable local, existe en todo el ámbito de la función main?. El código que muestras no debería causar problemas, sin más código no es posible la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso trabajando con fichero, tenía el mismo mensaje de violación de segmento y siguiendo foros he visto que la opción mas probable era que el fichero no se hubiera abierto correctamente. Así que para asegurarme, donde tenía:

```
void print_tetris_ascii()
{
    int c;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("tetris.txt", "r");
    c = fgetc(fp);

    fclose(fp);
```

he añadido el checkeo de que se haya abierto correctamente:

```
void print_tetris_ascii()
{
    int c;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("tetris.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) 
    { 
        printf("Cannot open file \n"); 
        exit(1); 
    } 
    c = fgetc(fp);

    fclose(fp);
```

Y efectivamente se ha impreso "Cannot open file \n" así que, al menos en mi caso, de ahí venía el segmentation fault parece! Si trabajas con ficheros te aconsejo que añadas ese check!! Aunque con stdin, como comenta eferion, el caso es distinto.

Comment: no está usando un fichero sino `stdin` ... ese stream está siempre abierto...